# How can I center index headings?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indexing

I have used following `example_style.ist` file  for creating index

```
headings_flag 1

heading_prefix "{ \\bfseries "
heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\\\n"
```

and in the preamble I have added  following

```
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options= -s example_style.ist]
```

and got out put as

[image]

Now the header is in left alinment. 
But I am in need of that   **A** and  **B** in center.

Is it possible to change **A** to center?

Comment: try with `heading_prefix "{\\bfseries\\hfil "  heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n"`

Comment: @touhami seems like an answer to me

Comment: @clemens done :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is

```
headings_flag 1

heading_prefix "{\\bfseries\\hfil "
heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\\\n"
```